# React Router pass props not in URL while being able to refresh page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my app, I have a long list of cities, and each one has a corresponding ID. Previously, I was using url params like this:

```
<Route exact path="/:cityid" component={SearchPage} />
```

However, now I want to use the city name itself in the url so that it is **/vancouver** instead of **/ab6e0d97**. I can get this to work fine, but my problem arises when I want to use the cityid in one of the following pages. Previously, I was passing the cityid along like this:

```
  props.history.push({
      pathname: `/${cityid}/personalize`
  })
```

and accessing it with `props.match.params`. Now, I have this:

```
    props.history.push({
      pathname: `/${city}/personalize`,
      state: { cityId }
    })
```

from `/:city/personalize`, I can access the cityId through `props.location`. However, when refreshing, I lose the `props.location` and cityId becomes defined. I need this cityId to be able to make a fetch request to get all the items associated with the cityId.

I imagine this is a common problem, but was not able to find a satisfactory answer to it, as I need two things:
1) city name in the url
2) cityid in the parts of the app that need it, without it having been passed in via the URL

Comment: It totally depends on your project but if you want to be able to refresh (wipe local memory) and keep the state your obvious choices are a cookie or local storage for your ID. There's nothing wrong with using a cookie for navigation. If you're using redux redux-persist is a great solution. https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Comment: interesting thought, I haven't actually considered that. I am using react-persist to keep users logged in currently. So I suppose in this scenario, what I could do is: when user selects a city, the cityid is sent to redux store, and then all further functions that require it will just have to retrieve it from state.

but then this begs another question: will users be able to simply navigate to url /vancouver?  It seems to me that I need to update the redux store with the associated cityid whenever a user navigates directly (ie. in address bar)

Comment: Any solution that works reliably is a solution. I'm a huge fan of clean URLs (bookmarks etc..) and there are a lot of ways to handle the solution. Local storage and cookies are not a hack, if the data isn't present in the URL use something persistent for persistent data (or persist the whole session with redux-persist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do much in this situation since only data that you have when entering page initially is the information within url (in your case city name).

You could use local storage to keep mapping between names and ids as suggested in comments but its pretty hacky solution - imagine sending someone else your url - he doesn't have anything in his local storage and gets error when opening that page.

Your best bet is to update your backend (if you have control over backend) to enable fetch by name (since they should be unique, right?). Then you could easily just do a fetch once user enters specific `/:city/personalize` using city name from `params`.